# How to get the last value entered

Tags: c#

I have a concurrent dictionary declared as global variable like

```
 private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
```

and Here I am adding values into it

```
 PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus[j] = iPageIndex - 1;
```

Now, I need to find out the last entered value in the dictionary.
How to get it?

Comment: You'll have to keep track of it separately, probably using an explicit 'last entry' variable. Dictionaries don't have a concept of order so 'last' doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @RandomStranger well the Dictionary rules stil apply

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Which you'll need to do carefully given that this is being manipulated from multiple threads.

Comment: @servy you can lock the dictionary, or instead of a variable, a list recording the order of elements